# Line bundles, sections and sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

I am trying to understand the connections between holomorphic vector (line) bundles, sections and sheaves in the simplest terms possible and I want to check that my interpretations are correct. I am somewhat familiar with bundles but certainly lack background in sheaves.

**Goal/question**: correct everything that might be wrong in the following interpretation, any nitpick will be welcome. **More concretely**: verify that for the sheaf morphism given below, the kernel $\ker \phi$ vanishes.

Consider $X=\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ the projective line, and two line bundles over it: $\mathcal{O}$, the trivial line bundle, and $\mathcal{O}(1)$, the hyperplane bundle. I wanted to make a connection between global sections $\phi\in H^0(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(1))$ and sheaf morphisms
$$
\mathcal{O}\overset{\phi}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{O}(1).
$$
Let us take a particularly simple one: $\phi\equiv z_0$, a homogeneous polynomial of degree $1$ in $(z_0,z_1)$.

**1: Interpret line bundles as sheaves**: for any line bundle $L$ of the above and
any open set $U\subset\mathbb{P}^1$ interpret define $\Gamma(U,L)$ to be the $\mathcal{O}(U)$-module of local sections of the line bundle $L$ over $U$. This defines a presheaf that turns out to be a sheaf.

**2: Interpret $\phi$ as a sheaf morphism**: for any **small** open set (i.e. $U$ contained in a trivializing open set of both bundles) I can map local sections of $\mathcal{O}$ to local sections of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ by multiplying by the polynomial $\phi$ in the corresponding homogeneous coordinates. In terms of the trivializations:

- Over $U_0=\{(z_0:z_1)|z_0\neq 0\}$, the section $\phi= z_0:U_0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(1)$ is written in terms of the trivialization $\mathcal{O}(1)(U_0)\simeq U_0\times \mathbb{C}$ as $\phi(\xi_0:\xi_1) \equiv ((\xi_0,\xi_1),1)$. Therefore $\phi$ as a map $\Gamma (U_0,\mathcal{O})\rightarrow \Gamma(U_0,\mathcal{O}(1))$ sends sections $f$ of $\mathcal{O}(U_0)\simeq U_0\times \mathbb{C}$ (which are nothing but holomorphic functions of $\frac{z_1}{z_0}$) to themselves. Clearly an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}(U_0)$-modules.
- Over $U_1=\{(z_0:z_1)|z_1\neq 0\}$, the section $\phi= z_0:U_1\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(1)$ is written in terms of the trivialization $\mathcal{O}(1)(U_1)\simeq U_1\times \mathbb{C}$ as $\phi(\xi_0:\xi_1) \equiv ((\xi_0,\xi_1),\frac{\xi_0}{\xi_1})$. Therefore $\phi$ as a map $\Gamma(U_1,\mathcal{O})\rightarrow \Gamma(U_1,\mathcal{O}(1))$ sends sections $f$ of $\mathcal{O}(U_1)\simeq U_1\times \mathbb{C}$ (holomorphic functions of $\frac{z_0}{z_1}$) to themselves $f(z_0/z_1)\cdot \frac{z_0}{z_1}$. This is not a surjection of sections but is certainly injective: only the zero section is mapped to the zero section.

The problem arises when considering bigger open sets, for example $\mathbb{P}^1$ itself. In that case, I do not have such a simple interpretation of sections as holomorphic function of some homogenized coordinates and it certainly cannot be an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces:
$$
\mathbb{C}\simeq \Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}) \rightarrow \text{span}_\mathbb{C}\{z_0,z_1\}\simeq \Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(1))
$$
simply by counting the dimensions!

**3: Consider kernel and quotient sheaves**: based on the calculations above, I think that *as a morphism of sheaves*, $\phi$ is injective, meaning that even though it vanishes at a point (0:1), no nonzero local section is mapped to a local zero section. This would imply that the sheaf $\ker \phi = 0$.

Much more difficult would be to construct the cokernel sheaf $\mathcal{O}(1) / \text{im }\phi$. It will certainly not correspond to a line bundle as it is impossible that it is locally free.

Comment: The cokernel is what is called a *skyscraper sheaf*, supported on a divisor. What happens at the zero divisor of $\phi$?